# PHP placing user input in a file

Tags: php, html

I have this register form that doesn't work the way you would think.

All it does it out the email and password into a file, and it won't be used again, just stored.

The code isn't working, somebody help me?

Literally nothing is being out into he file, although it does make the file.

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Earn and Learn</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="login-wrap">
      <div class="form">

        <form method="post" action="email.php">
          <h2>Create Account</h2>
          <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" required autocomplete="off"/>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
          <button type="submit"> Sign Up </button>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Email.php:

```
<?php
  $text=$_POST["email"];
  $var_str = var_export($text, true);
  $var = "$text = $var_str";
  file_put_contents('filename.txt', "\nEmail:" '$text',FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: are you creating a new file or modifying an already existing file? do you have read/write permissions on the folder you are trying to write to?

Comment: How could you respect that code able to perform login?

Comment: I have full permission, and it'll create the file but if it already exists appends it with new information

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're using @TheOne ? There seems to be an error in `"\nEmail:" '$text'` which wouldn't result in a successful function call

Comment: What's the error? I'm using this code but it's not working. Is that the problem?

Comment: This doesn't compile. Even if it did, placing in your variable inside single quotes disables interpolation. Use `"\nEmail:$text"`. See also https://3v4l.org/L7hoB

Comment: There was a missing concatenation dot between `"\nEmail:" '$text'` and extra quotes around the `$text` variable. It should be `"\nEmail:" . $text`.  But string interpolation is always more readable: `"\nEmail:{$text}"`

Answer (score 6):

Give this a shot:

```
<?php
  $text = $_POST["email"];
  file_put_contents('filename.txt',"\nEmail: {$text}",FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

That second argument to `file_put_contents()` looked like two separate strings instead of one and you can just put the `$text` variable inside the single string like so if you use a double-quoted string.

Comment: @TheOne No problem, check out the answer from sidyll as well, that's a better explanation of why I wrote that second line the way I did.

Answer (score 1):

Your function call has a mistake:

```
file_put_contents('filename.txt', "\nEmail:" '$text',FILE_APPEND);
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I recommend you enabling warnings  and errors because this wouldn't even
compile. Would trow a parse error.  You can't have two strings separated
by whitespace.  If you  want to concatenate  strings, use  `.`. However,
note that to  interpolate a variable value in a  string, you need double
quotes. So, here are some possible solutions:

- `"\nEmail:" . $text`
- `"\nEmail: $text"`

Using string concatenation,  for another example, you  can also simplify
this:

```
$text=$_POST["email"];
$var_str = var_export($text, true);
$var = "$text = $var_str";
```

To this:

```
$var = $_POST['email'] . '=' . var_export($_POST['email'], true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$email = $_POST["email"];

$content = "Email: ".$email."\r\n".
           "line 2\r\n".
           "line 3\r\n".
           "line 4\r\n"; 

#creating new file
   $myfile = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folderpath/filename.txt","wb");
   fwrite($myfile, $content);
   fclose($myfile);

#append to file
   $myfile = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folderpath/filename.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
   fwrite($myfile, "\n".$content);
   fclose($myfile);
```